# ACF Filed - Adding link not working the button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a sidebar and it has a button.

I have a "button_url" field where I enter some URL.

The button need open the URL entered in the above field in a new tab.

I wrote the code like this, and it doesn't work.

```
<?php $button_url = get_field('button_url'); ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var button_url = '<?php echo $button_url; ?>';
$("#myBtn").attr("href", button_url);
});
</script>
```

I set the Sidebar Widget as follows:

```
<a href="" id="myBtn">button</a>
```

The problem is that in the page code it looks like this:

```
<a href="" id="myBtn" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> button </a>
```

Something in sync between them doesn't work, and the sidebar doesn't get the URL entered in the field. That's the problem

Comment: What is the error in the developer console?

Comment: Hey @Yyg, maybe I'm missing the issue but if the issue is just that the link is not opening in a new tab you would want to add a target to your `href` `target="_blank"` should work.  If there is another issue please do as the above comment asks and share the error in your console, or provide some more details to as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the page code it looks like this:

```
<a href="" id="myBtn" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> button </a>
```

Something in sync between them doesn't work, and the sidebar doesn't get the URL entered in the field. That's the problem